# Google Cloud - creating sink

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, sink

Im trying to export logs in to bigquery using sink from the cloud shell.
I did the following steps:
bq mk dataset

gcloud beta logging sinks create my-bq-sink \
      bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/my-project/datasets/\
  my_dataset --log-filter='resource.type="gce_instance"'

I created a service account for the sink and bind him to bigQuery.dataEditor and logging.logWriter

The problem is that if im not going to the console-> edit sink -> update sink im getting that my access to the dataset was denied. how can i solve that from cloud shell?

Answer (score 2):

Like in many products, creating a service is separate from the IAM authorization. For the logging sink, the "strange" decision from Google has been to generate a service account by the logging service and to send you the name of this service account in the command result

```
Created [https://logging.googleapis.com/v2/projects/My_PROJECT/sinks/test].
Please remember to grant `serviceAccount:p78401601954-957849@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com` the BigQuery Data Editor role on the dataset.
More information about sinks can be found at https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/export/configure_export
```

Not very usable if you want to script something. So, add the parameter `--format=json` into the sink creation command and the result is the following

```
{
  "createTime": "2020-05-21T19:27:36.599050569Z",
  "destination": "bigquery.googleapis.com/projects/My_PROJECT/datasets/asset_eu",
  "filter": "resource.type=cloud_function",
  "name": "test",
  "updateTime": "2020-05-21T19:27:36.599050569Z",
  "writerIdentity": "serviceAccount:p78401601954-465055@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

Now you can get the `writerIdentity` and grant the role that you need on it. However, I repeat, this choice is strange for Google (and not consistant with other products) and I won't be surprised that this behavior change in the future.

Comment: I used sink description to get the writerIdentity and i created a SA with the biqeury permission ans logs writes permission. the problem is that its working only after im going to the GCP console and click on UPDATE SINK

Comment: What do you mean by "I created the SA"? You don't have to create it, only grant the role that you want.

Comment: i created a new service account (Under the IAM) using the unique writer identity. should i just give permissions to:
p78401601954-465055@gcp-sa-logging.iam.gserviceaccount.com?

Comment: Yes!! You simply have to grant permissions to the provided service account after the sink creation! No service account to create